# How to know is there user added libraries into the project programmatically?

Tags: android, android-library

In my project, I have included user created libraries. I want to check is there libraries present in project. 
How I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by user created libraries ?

Answer (score 0):

Below code may help

```
   public static void checkLibrary(){
                try {
                    Log.e(" i am in","checklibrary");
                    Set<String> libs = new HashSet<String>();
                    String mapsFile = "/proc/" + android.os.Process.myPid() + "/maps";
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(mapsFile));
                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        if (line.endsWith(".so")) {
                            int n = line.lastIndexOf(" ");
                            libs.add(line.substring(n + 1));
                        }
                    }
                    Log.e("Ldd", libs.size() + " libraries:");
                    for (String lib : libs) {
                        Log.e("Ldd", lib);
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // Do some error handling...
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // Do some error handling...
                }
            }
```